# How can I change the horizontal scrollbar to a dot in my table?

Tags: php, html, css

I have a table with horizontal scrolling, but I dont like the scrollbar, so I want to change it to a dot.
I tried using flickity but I have some problems.

Code:

```
<head>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" 
          href= 
"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> 
</head>
<body>
    <style>
.scrollme {
    overflow-x: auto; 
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 2px;
  height:5px;
}
 }
    </style>
    <div class="container"  >    
    <?php       
     require 'db.php';  
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM clelist order by clelist_id DESC"; 
            $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql );
            echo "<div class='carousel  scrollme' style='' data-flickity="" data-js='carousel'>
                <table class='table table-bordered text-center table-responsive '>
                    <tr class='table-active '>
                        <th class='text-center align-middle carousel-cell' style=' white-space:nowrap;' > num </th>
                        <th class='text-center align-middle carousel-cell 'style=' white-space:nowrap;'  > car_num</th>
                         <!--more.....-->
                    </tr>";

                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    $tmp=explode(":",$row['cle_date']); 
                     
                    echo '
                        <tbody id="searchTable">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="text-center align-middle carousel-cell"  > 
                                '.$row["DlistNO"].'<br>'.$row["cle_no"].'
                            </td>
                             
                            <td class="text-center align-middle carousel-cell" > 
                                '.$row["cle_date"].'<br>
                                '.$row["c_cle_car_no_head"].'<br>
                                '.$row["c_cle_car_no_tail"].'
                            </td>
                               <!--more.....-->
                             ';
                            ?>
                             
                        <tr>
                    <?php   
                }
                 
        ?></tbody>
                </table></div>  
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:
[image: output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this answer your question: https://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/01/21/dot-navigation-styles/

Also, you can check out different types of scroll dots [here](https://tympanus.net/Development/DotNavigationStyles/)

Comment: @samurai, the same will work for tr and td 